# multiply and display text from input and text from div and display it in div with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I guess i dont parse properly the text to number/float input type number is fine but i guess divs dont have property 'type'

```
<body>
            <div class="wrapper" ng-app="">
                <div id="usd" class="type-container">
                    <div id="usd-type" class="boxes type">USD</div>
                    <input  id="usd-input-value" class="boxes" type="number" ng-model="usd">
                    <div ng-model="usdrate"  id="usdrate" class="boxes rate"></div>
                    <div  id="usd-output" class="boxes output">{{Number(usd) * usdrate}}</div>              
                </div>
                <div id="gpb" class="type-container">
                    <div id="gpb-type" class="boxes type">GPB</div>
                    <input id="gbp-input-value" class="boxes" type="text">
                    <div id="gbprate" class="boxes rate"></div>
                    <div id="gbp-output" class="boxes output"></div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1"></script>            
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval(function(){
                jQuery.ajax({                   
                url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22%2C%22USDCHF%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $('#usdrate').text(response.query.results.rate[0].Rate*1.955);
                    $('#gbprate').text(response.query.results.rate[1].Rate*1.955);
                    //console.log(response.query.results.rate[0].Rate);
                }
                });},500);
        });

        </script>
    </body>
```

This is the whole code except the css which is not important to share at this point

Answer (score 0):

Run the following snippet.

Check the code to see how I use an angular app, and then initialise an angular module.

In the module, I use `$scope` to interact with the page, and then in order to multiply I am using a getter function, which I called `mult()`.

Feel free to ask for any help. :)

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22%2C%22USDCHF%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          $scope.usdrate = Number(response.query.results.rate[0].Rate * 1.955);
          $('#usdrate').text($scope.usdrate);
          $scope.gbprate = Number(response.query.results.rate[1].Rate * 1.955);
          $('#gbprate').text($scope.gbprate);
          //console.log(response.query.results.rate[0].Rate);
        }
      });
    }, 500);
  });

  $scope.mult = function() {
    return $scope.usdrate * $scope.usd;
  }



});
```

```html
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="usd" class="type-container">
      <div id="usd-type" class="boxes type">USD</div>
      <input id="usd-input-value" class="boxes" type="number" ng-model="usd">
      <div id="usdrate" class="boxes rate"></div>
      <div id="usd-output" class="boxes output">{{mult()}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="gpb" class="type-container">
      <div id="gpb-type" class="boxes type">GPB</div>
      <input id="gbp-input-value" class="boxes" type="text">
      <div id="gbprate" class="boxes rate"></div>
      <div id="gbp-output" class="boxes output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

*Sources:*

- [AngularJS Fundamentals in 60 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM): A great watch in order to understand AngularJS apps and modules.
- AngularJS [Scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: editted im really new to AngularJS and im currently learning it

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov - I have updated the answer with a full solution for you. :) Good luck on your Angular path. :)